# subgroup proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove that if $G$ is an abelian group, then
$H =\{ x \in G\mid x^{2} = e \}$
is a subgroup of $G$.
I did show that $H$ is close, associative, have identity and inverse element. Then my prof said I need to show that $H$ is non-empty before showing other axioms. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: Every group has an identity, so........

Comment: If you have shown that $H$ has identity, then $H$ **is** non-empty.  I don't understand your professor's comment.  Maybe he/she didn't read your work very carefully?

Comment: I firmly believe that while proving certain "objects" have definite structure, one must be first certain about its' existence. So that's why your professor wanted you to see whether $H$ is empty or not on the first instance. If it  was empty then there's no point of proving other properties.

Comment: He said that I have to show that H is a nonempty first, then I can show the rest of axioms.

Comment: Logically it is not necessary to prove nonemptiness before the other things, because proving it has the identity takes care of that. However sometimes an instructor wants a proof or calculation done in accordance with a specific template, and it seems yours wanted you to prove nonemptiness as a first step.

Answer (score 1):

The identity satisfies that equation.